# How do i deal with a NoReverseMatch?

Tags: django, django-urls

i have a function,

```
def show_checkout(request,id):
    if order.is_empty(request):
        cart_url = urlresolvers.reverse('order_index')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(cart_url)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        resto = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,instance=restaurant)
        if form.is_valid():
            order_created = create_order(request,resto)
            .....
    return render(request,'checkout/checkout.html',context)
```

in this next view i try to submit a form,

```
def show_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        if postdata['submit'] == 'checkout':
            checkout_url = checkout.get_checkout_url(request)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(checkout_url)
```

the above view calls this view in checkout.py

```
def get_checkout_url(request):
    return urlresolvers.reverse('checkout')
```

the urls.py
`url(r'^checkout/(?P<id>\w+)$',show_checkout,name="checkout"),`

after all this i get error,
`Reverse for 'checkout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`
i thought i was on the right track, i guess i wasn't.

edit
in `show_order` i do

```
def show_order(request,id):
    resto = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=id)
    ...
        if postdata['submit'] == 'checkout':
#           checkout_url = checkout.get_checkout_url(request)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('checkout',kwargs={'id':resto}))
```

in urls i do `url(r'^your_order/(?P<id>\w+)$',show_order,name="order_index"),`
raises error `page not found`

complete urls.py

```
from .views import show_item,show_checkout,show_order,get_category,homepage,reciept
from f4l import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',homepage,name="homepage"),
    url(r'^menu/(\d+)$',get_category, name="f4l_menu"),
    url(r'^your_order/(?P<id>\w+)$',show_order,name="order_index"),
    url(r'^item/(?P<id>\w+)/$',show_item, name="item_order"),
    url(r'^checkout/(?P<id>\w+)$',show_checkout,name="checkout"),
    url(r'^reciept/$',reciept,name="checkout_reciept"),
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this get_checkout_url function and need to pass the id argument for the url.

Instead of `return HttpResponseRedirect(checkout_url)` try this:

```
HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('checkout',kwargs={'id':your_id}))
```

Comment: I forgot one thing, and I am mading the correction on the answer

Comment: @SuziemacTani yes, please.

Comment: @Fernado Freitas Alves, i just did

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('live.views',
    url(r'^$', 'homepage', name="homepage"),
    url(r'^menu/(\d+)/$', 'get_category', name="f4l_menu"),
    url(r'^your_order/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'show_order', name="order_index"),
    url(r'^item/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'show_item', name="item_order"),
    url(r'^checkout/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'show_checkout', name="checkout"),
    url(r'^reciept/$', 'reciept', name="checkout_reciept"),


def show_order(request,id):
    resto = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=id)
    ...
        if postdata['submit'] == 'checkout':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('live:order_index',kwargs={
                'id':id}))
```

Comment: thanks but this still raises page not found, ma urls `url(r'^your_order/(?P<id>\w+)$',show_order,name="order_index"),`

Comment: well, after customer ordering an item, they get to chckout `show_order`, `show_order` calls `show_checkout` which is a form to be filled.

Comment: so, it still not working out..but thanks, by the end of the day i will figure something out

Comment: don't be... will figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You should use `resto.id` rather than just `resto` in `reverse()` like

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('checkout',kwargs={'id':resto.id}))
```

instead of

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('checkout',kwargs={'id':resto}))
```

Comment: my urls `url(r'^your_order/(?P<id>\w+)$',show_order,name="order_index"),` could it be the problem